# How to pass dynamic values to event listener

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using a server side technology (JSP) to render my views. Therefore I have a `for` loop that loops through a list. Now, I want to bind a click listener to a button that is rendered for each item in the list. The code in the click listener needs the item ID, which I don't understand how to pass to the JavaScript code.

I also use `requirejs`, if that matter to the solution.

Comment: Can you post the code you have for the loop, and how you have the item ID's defined?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just don't need to pass the html ID to your javascript. You can use a css class to retrieve your buttons in your DOM. The javascript code depends of what framework you use.

In native javascript, you can retrieve your buttons like this :

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.my_class');
```

Just replace `my_class` by what you want.

You can access a button id by doing this :

```
var button_id = buttons[0].id
```

If you want to attach the item id to the button, you can use a `data` attribute. For example :

```
<button id="my_button" data-id="item_id" />
```

In the javascript, you can access to `data_id` like this :

```
var item_id = buttons[0].getAttribute('data-id');
```

Comment: If I use a `data-id` attribute, would that break anything in older browsers? Am I free to add own attributes like this, I have not seen this before so I must ask.

Comment: It works on all recent browser and all IE7+ perfectly. I think it also works on IE6, but i have never tested it myself.

Comment: Is data-id an attribute from the HTML spec? Or do you just make such attributes yourself?

Comment: data- attributes are part of HTML5 (see http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ ). But it works with older browsers. You can use an html5 shiv to make sure : http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score 1):

In most event handlers, `this` is the DOM node that triggered the event, so something like this works:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nameIsNull/HPp5m/)
If you were using jQuery and requirejs this would be like this:

```
require(['jQuery'], function ($) {
    $('.container_element').on('click', '.button_class', function () {
        console.log('You have clicked button with id ', $(this).attr('id'));
    })
})
```